# Template + Channel + Category structure

Tags: channel, categories

I need help figuring out how to organize the following. Within my main EE site, there will be a SECTION. Within that, multiple YEARS. Within each YEAR, multiple LOCATIONS. Within each LOCATION, multiple articles or pages. My brain is going in circles. I'm planning one style of page for the SECTION index, while all other pages will have the same style or structure.

Should it be:

Template Group = SECTION 
SECTION = index, location 1, location 2, location 3 (templates with channels specific to each location) and then categories assigned to each article for the year?

or

Template Group = SECTION_YEAR
Template Group = SECTION_YEAR
Template Group = SECTION_YEAR

And then within each group: index, location 1, location 2, location 3, with one type of category to handle the content structure of each page?

I intend to sort the menu into:
YEAR DROPDOWN Location 1 Location 2 Location 3, with each article per location showing up under its location.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It all depends on how the data is entered. What are your Channels and are you using any categories?

Comment: Well - that is part of my question. When/what to use the channels and categories for. Should each location be a channel, with a category specifying the year, then each article makes its own page? Or should the template determine the location, the channel be the year and then the category just determine the category fields that show up for each article?

Comment: As a side note, 1 year of this is set up already, I'm expanding it to include multiple years. Currently, the channel is for the location, there are no categories, and there is a limit="1" so that there is one entry per page.

Comment: Always try and think in terms of content first. What are the actual entries? If they are articles then create an Articles channel. Year and location *sound* like properties of an entry rather than an entry themselves. So one step at a time, focus on the content before considering the templates. Let me know what an 'entry' is and I can advise on channels, template groups, and templates.

Comment: An entry, ie, the content of the lowest level page, is headline, subhead, paragraphs of text and embedded images. These are organized, going from the bottom up, into locations and then by year. There will be multiple entries per location and the locations will be the same each year. This is the "section", a smaller piece of a much bigger site. [http://www.sea.edu/spice233] I need to add a whole new navigation structure, to accommodate year 2012 and soon 2013

Comment: At the moment the site isn't loading(?) so I'll check back later on. Generally though think of a descriptive name to give these 'entries'. Is it an article? A blog entry? A Page? etc. EE works on 'Channels' (types) of information so you need to think in terms of describing resources. Years and publish dates are 'meta' information so that can be accommodated in the URL schema once we know what 'types' of data we're dealing with.

Comment: Sorry - the site was down last night for about 6 hours. Yes, the final product for could be considered an article. I didn't set this site up initially and from what I can tell, the categories have been used primarily to differentiate what category of content is showing up, within a specific channel, not necessarily the type of content (page, blog entry, etc). So the site already has 153 channels, 58 category groups, and I think the last category I made was #330 or so.